# findTokens: in Pharo versus Dolphin Smalltalk

Tags: smalltalk, pharo, dolphin-smalltalk

I want to split a String in Pharo 4. My input is

```
'a %% b %% c %%% d %% e %% f'
```

and I want to get

```
#('a %% b %% c' 'd %% e %% f')
```

thus the separator is ' %%% '

In [Dolphin 7](http://www.object-arts.com/) it works nice:

```
'a %% b %% c %%% d %% e %% f' subStrings: ' %%% '
#('a %% b %% c' 'd %% e %% f')
```

But in [Pharo 4](http://www.pharo.org) seems to be broken:

```
'a %% b %% c %%% d %% e %% f' subStrings: ' %%% '
"#('a' 'b' 'c' 'd' 'e' 'f')"
```

There is a way to get the Dolphin behavior in Pharo?

Comment: Have you considered a simpler approach such as `'a %% b %% c %%% d %% e %% f' readStream upToAll: ' %%% '`?

Comment: Yes but that would not work with a longer sequence `'a %% b %% c %%% d %% e %% f %%% g %% h %% i' readStream upToAll: ' %%% '`

Comment: Sure, my code was just a hint. You would need to collect the results of `upToAll:` in a `[stream atEnd] whileFalse: [result add: (stream upToAll: ' %%%% ')]` way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
'a %% b %% c %%% d %% e %% f' splitOn: ' %%% '
```

It also works with

```
'a %% b %% c %%% d %% e %% f %%% g %% h %% i' splitOn: ' %%% '
```

Comment: It can also work with: `' %%% ' split: 'a %% b %% c %%% d %% e %% f' `